# Datepicker duplicate issue javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to reset datepicker onclick event but click on button datepicker will be duplicate. How to reset datepicker without duplication.
Here i'm Initialize datepicker

```
  function datePicker()
        {

          var datePickerValue =  $('.datepicker-start').val();

            var date = new Date(datePickerValue);
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);


            var dd = date.getDate();
            var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            var newEndDate = y + '-'+ mm + '-'+ dd;


                $('.datepicker-end').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                    minDate: newEndDate,
                });

        }
```

> this is code for reset datepicker

```
function reset()
{
    $('#datepicker2').datepicker('setDate', null);
}
```

> here is i call reset function

Close

[check that pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Ive.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are destroying the date picker or just setting the value to null? There should be something like `$(selector).datepicker('destroy')` to remove an instance.

Comment: Why are you using two date pickers  ````$('.datepicker-end').datetimepicker( ```` and  ```$('#datepicker2').datepicker(```  ?

Comment: not reset datepicker

Comment: am using two date pikers for getting two dates difference

Answer (score 0):

jquery datetimepicker can be reset using below line.

```
$('#input').datetimepicker('reset');
```